# How to reconfigure an existing confluent kafka producer instance in C#?

Tags: confluent-platform

I have a kafka producer initialized as follows:

```
var config = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "bootstrap.servers", BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS } };
Producer _producer = new Producer(config);
```

After the initialization, when I am about to produce a message on a particular topic I want to add compression to the producer (Only for the topic). I need to add the compression config { "compression.codec", "gzip" }.

How can I do this?